# Filename of the local MongoBD database

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, local-database

I have been using MongoDB for my projects. I know that the database is stored locally in */data/db* directory. But i would like to know the exact filename or Collection of filenames of the database file.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Simply run `ls /data/db/*` - what else you like to know?